# How to alter a view results?

Tags: views, 8, hooks

For example, there is a view.

The view has been executed and has results.

How can I alter these results. For example, I need to change the letter "a" to the letter "b" in result of some field.

How can I do it ?

I'm looking into hook_views_pre_render and hook_views_post_render, but can't understand how to get results and how to change them.

Could you share your experience how to do it ? Or could you share useful links ?

Comment: There are several options, in UI you can rewrite a field and use the `replace` twig filter, in theming you can use a views field template or in a module you can extend a views field plugin and override `render`.

Comment: Can I do it using hook_view_pre_render or hook_view_post_render hooks ? It's more comfortable for my current task.

Comment: The comments on the 8.2.x version of the [hook_views_pre_render documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/8.2.x) give some examples of how to update field data in `hook_view_pre_render`.

Comment: The 8.2.x page is no longer available but as been archived.  https://web.archive.org/web/20210506130315/https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/8.2.x